# A person who finds peace or pleasure in seeing other people in same trouble that he is in

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider a person who is in pain, sad and in a difficult position/situation, and finds another man in the same situation and feels happy. What would we call such a person?

There is a word having its roots in German, "schadenfreude", which means "to derive pleasure from someone else's misfortune", but this does not fit exactly here as *schadenfreude* does not take the situation of the subject into consideration.

It cannot be sadism either, as that is when the person revels in inflicting pain.

There is a sense of camaraderie in this situation where the person relates to the pain of the others and somehow his own pain is alleviated.

Is there a more precise word to fit the bill?

Comment: We have a saying: "Misery loves company".  But that does not answer the question of what such a person is called.

Comment: @GEdgar, I think "misery loves company" is exactly the phrase that describes the OP's scenario.  The person sees someone else with the same problem and is happy - not in the other's misery but that they, themself, are not alone in the same misery.

Comment: Not really an answer but [apt and funny](http://sawbonessurio.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/calvin_hobbes-susie-bad-mood.jpg?w=700).

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like [commiseration](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/commiseration?s=t). In which case, you could call that person a *commiserator*.

Comment: Commiseration does not imply camaraderie or shared pain.

Comment: @terdon: Why not? I would commiserate with the person in the hospital bed next to me.

Comment: Yes you would, but you would also commiserate with a friend who just lost someone whether or not you were also in mourning. The OP is asking for a word that implies a _shared_ pain.

Comment: @terdon: Perhaps the word can be used to imply sympathy, but it does not preclude empathy due to a shared pain. A word may exist that zeroes in on that single relationship, but I think that, in context, an injured person empathizing with someone of similar injury could be called a commiserator.

Comment: Yes indeed. All I am saying is that a "commiserator" is not necessarily someone who shares the pain. They can be but they don't need to be.

Comment: @terdon: In sloppy modern parlance, people will say they *commiserate* with you when all they really mean is they *regret* your pain, rather than *share* it. But tylerharms is perfectly correct - and I'd go even further, saying that to a *careful* speaker, commiseration is much more about empathy than sympathy (as the etymology itself would suggest).

Comment: @FumbleFingers the definition linked to mentions empathy and sympathy, neither of which imply _shared_ pain. If I empathize with you I will take your pain as my own but I did not have it to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

"gloat" means self satisfaction, often at an adversary's misfortune.

Comment: Agreed, but so does Shadenfreude. It speaks nothing of the situation of the person under consideration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a phrase *Welcome to my world* which suggests a satisfaction at someone understanding how uncomforatble I am.

The term *simpatico* [means](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/simpatico?q=simpatico), among other things

> having or characterized by shared attributes or interests

While it suggests satisfaction in the alignment of chacarteristics, this term does not necessarily imply compatability based on suffering.